# Cleaner way to convert from CStringW to std::string?

Tags: c++, string

I figured out a somewhat convoluted way to convert a `CStringW` to a `std::string`, but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way than:

```
CStringW cwstr;
std::wstring stdwstr = cwstr;
std::string stdstr = CW2T(stdwstr.c_str());
```

Comment: Why mark this as community wiki?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cut out the intermediate `std::wstring`:

```
CStringW cwstr;
std::string stdstr = CW2A(cwstr);
```

Also note that you want the `CW2A` macro for correctness.  `CW2T` converts to a `TCHAR` string, so the code you posted would only compile for an ANSI build (where `TCHAR` is `char`).

Answer (score 4):

```
std::string str = CStringA( cwstr );
```

Job done.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` has the following constructor:

```
template<class InputIterator> string (InputIterator begin, InputIterator end);
```

So you could use it:

```
CStringW cwstr;
std::string x( &cwstr.GetString()[0], &cwstr.GetString()[cwstr.GetLength()] );
```

Implicit convertion `wchar_t` to `char` will take place.

Comment: Do you need `&` before those?

Comment: Your solution gives me: `error C2102: '&' requires l-value` (testing without ampersand now)

Comment: Something changed in `CString` since I've used it last time. Fixed. But now it's not so clear.